# Make processes like a binary tree and make each child do a different thing

Tags: c, linux

I'm doing the following program where I create various processes like they were a binary tree, I want the child from "the left" to do a different thing from the child of the "right" but it's outputting me 2 children at the right or 2 children at the left and I don't want that.

```
void slice(int dir){
    if (dir == 1) {
        printf("izq ");
        printf("child pid %d   parent pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if (dir == 2){
        printf("der ");
        printf("child pid %d   parent pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());fflush(stdout);
    }
}

void vector(int vector[], int length, int niveles){
    for(int i=1;i<=niveles;i++)
    {
    int error = 0;
pid_t child_pid[2] = { -1, -1 };
for (int dir=0; dir<=1; ++dir) {
    child_pid[dir] = fork();
    if (child_pid[dir] == -1) {
        error = 1;
        perror("fork");
    }

    if (child_pid[dir] == 0) { 
       // Here is where you place the code the child should execute.
       slice(dir);
       exit(0);
    }
}

for (int dir=0; dir<=1; ++dir) {
    if (child_pid[dir] == -1)
       continue;

    int status;
    pid_t pid = waitpid(child_pid[dir], &status, 0);
    if (pid == -1) {
        error = 1;
        perror("waitpid");
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        error = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "Child was killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    }
    else if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
        error = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with error %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
}

if (error)
   exit(1);
   } 
}
```

My goal is to call a function for "izq" that does a different thing from "der" while keeping the whole binary tree idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that both the parent and the child proceed to execute from the `fork`, so you need something like the following:

```
int error = 0;
pit_t child_pid[2] = { -1, -1 };
for (int dir=0; dir<=1; ++dir) {
    child_pid[dir] = fork();
    if (child_pid[dir] == -1) {
        error = 1;
        perror("fork");
    }

    if (child_pid[dir] == 0) { 
       // Here is where you place the code the child should execute.
       exit(0);
    }
}

for (int dir=0; dir<=1; ++dir) {
    if (child_pid[dir] == -1)
       continue;

    int status;
    pid_t pid = waitpid(child_pid[dir], &status, 0);
    if (pid == -1) {
        error = 1;
        perror("waitpid");
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        error = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "Child was killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(wstatus));
    }
    else if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
        error = 1;
        fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with error %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
    }
}

if (error)
   exit(1);
```

Comment: edited my post, i tried to adapt it to my code but it only creates "niveles" children to "izq", it never enters to the "der" condition, i need each parent to create 2 children "niveles" times, one for izq condition and one for der condition